# Is it possible to access scale_length during add-on registration?

Tags: python, add-on

I am writing an add-on. There are UI elements using `FloatProperty`. Some of them should have minimum, maximum and default values in absolute terms. This requires the knowledge of the user's scale_length.

These values have to be defined when the add-on is registered. The `register()` method does not receive a `context`. `bpy.context` and `bpy.data.scenes` are not available yet at this point.

Is there a way to access the user's scale_length?

Comment: I think one good approach is adding a [checkbox to the panel header](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147054/how-to-add-a-checkbox-to-a-panel-header/147058#147058) and when checked/updated call a function to set or init the limits based on another property. Another approach is using a [handler per file load](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150977/31447), which always feels a bit crappy.

Comment: @brockmann Thanks, that looks awesome! But then I run into the problem of re-registering the FloatProperty. This was discussed here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18686/66651 . I managed to re-register in the console, still struggle to put it in the source properly. But even if I manage that, can I expect stable behaviour?

Comment: Pedestrian solution would be to check the limits in the update functions.